# C program is not showing output even though it is getting compiled

Tags: arrays, c, runtime-error

This is the code for finding the numerical solutions of 1D Heat Transfer Equation(well, possibly). The code is getting compiled but the console is not showing any output. The console is staying and not disappearing either. I have tried with getch() and getchar() also but the problem still persists. Please help!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int
main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  int a, p, tmax, tmin, l;
  int i, j, n, o;
  double m, T1, T2, x, al, H[l + 1][tmax + 1];
  float k;

  printf ("Enter the number of nodes: \n");
  scanf ("%d", &a);

  printf ("Enter the thickness of the wall: \n");
  scanf ("%d", &l);

  printf ("Enter the value of maximum time coordinate: \n");
  scanf ("%d", &tmax);

  printf ("Enter the value of minimum time coordinate: \n");
  scanf ("%d", &tmin);

  printf ("Enter the number of time steps: \n");
  scanf ("%d", &p);

  printf ("Enter the value of thermal diffusivity: \n");
  scanf ("%f", &k);

  printf ("Enter the value of initial temperature: \n");
  scanf ("%lf", &T1);

  printf ("Enter the values of temperature at both the boundaries: \n");
  scanf ("%lf", &T2);

  x = (l / (a - 1));   /*change in spacial coordinate*>
  m = (tmax - tmin) / (p - 1);    /*change in time coordinate*/
  al = (k * (m)) / (pow (x, 2));   /*Formula for CFL constant*/
  
  printf (" The vale of the constant is %lf\n", al);
  printf ("the value of the constant should be less than 0.5 for the convergence of iterative 
  formula. \n");

  for (o = 0; o <= tmax; o++)
    {
      H[0][o] = H[l][o] = T2;   /*boundary condition*/
    }

  for (j = 1; j <= (l - 1); j++)
    {
      H[j][0] = T1;   /*initial condition*/
    }

  if (al <= 0.5)
    {
      
      for (n = 0; n <= (tmax - 1); n++)
    {
      for (i = 1; i <= (l - 1); i++)
        {
          H[i][n + 1] =
        H[i][n] + (al * (H[i + 1][n] - (2 * H[i][n]) + H[i - 1][n]));    /* Iterative Formula for finding the temperature at each grid point*/
          printf (" The value of Temperature[i,n] at [i,n] is:\n ");
          printf ("%lf at %d , %d is", H[i][n], i, n);
          printf ("\n");
        }
    }
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("Error! Solution is unstable. \n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Also, how can I take a mathematical function as input from the user instead of `T2` in the place of the initial temperature? Sometimes, 1D unsteady heat transfer problems has initial temperature in the form of a mathematical function which can be algebric, trigonometric, hyperbolic etc. like in this problem

"Show that the solution of the ∂2θ/∂x2=  ∂θ/∂t
satisfying the conditions (i) θ → 0 as t → ∞, (ii) θ = 0
when x = ±a for all values of t > 0, and (iii) θ = x when t = 0 and −a < x < a is

θ(x,t) =   2a/π ∑(n=1) to ∞((-1)^(n-1))*(1/n)*(sin⁡(nπx/a) * (exp^((-((nπ)^2)* t)/a^2 )))"

So, I need to take a mathematical function as input from the user. Is there any way to do that using the C standard library? I found a way to do it using expression evaluator/parser but is there any other simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify: are you actually *running* the program? That's not the same thing as compiling it.  And if you do run it, are you getting any output at all (for example, the input prompts)?

Comment: `H[0][o]` interesting choice of variable, kinda looks like a cockeyed owl...

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this is related to your issue, but `x = (l / (a - 1))` is probably erroneous.  Since `l` and `a` both have integer types, the division is an integer (truncating) division.

Comment: The declaration of H is definitely erroneous.  It is a variable-length array declaration with array dimensions depending on `l` and `tmax`, but at the point of declaration, `l` and `tmax` have indeterminate values.  If you want to declare `H` that way then `l` and `tmax` need already to have the wanted values at the point where `H`'s declaration appears.

Comment: It is suspicious that you input `tmin` and use it to compute `m`, but otherwise seem to assume that values of the time coordinate start at 0.

Comment: `H[l + 1][tmax + 1];` `H` will not track changes in `l` and `tmax`, it will be created with the sise according to their current values at the time of the declaration, and keep that size throughout. Since said values are indeterminate, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: the program is kind of working if ```H[l + 1][tmax + 1];``` is declare in the end of all ```scanf```s .

Comment: "the console is not showing any output" ... if the program did not `printf ("Enter the number of nodes: \n");` then the problem is before then as commented.

Comment: yes `H[l + 1][tmax + 1]`  is eilligal`arrays has to be defined with fixed dimensions, you can-#t use variables

Comment: @John Bollinger I am running the program but it is not showing any input prompts. Can you please show me the code on how to declare H. I have to take the values of `l` and `tmax` as inputs from the user. About `tmin`, I will assign its value to 0 instead of taking it from the user.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Can you please tell how to deal with this problem of declaring this array H? I have to take the values `l` and `tmax` from the users as inputs.

Comment: @Jarvis__-_-__ Okay, will try this out.

Comment: Declare it after you take the input from the user. Be aware that the user crash your program by entering too large values for `l` and `tmax`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  Okay, got it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your second question about inputting formulas is entirely different from the first one, and you should ask it in a separate post (after searching to see if there is an existing question that it might duplicate).  But generally the answer is "no, there is no such feature in the standard library, you have to implement a parser".

Comment: @nbk, C has supported variable-length arrays since C99.  Although that feature is optional since C11, there is no reason to expect that an implementation that exercises its option to omit VLA support would fail at runtime instead of at compile time when presented with the OP's code.